# Container not starting with GenericContainer

Tags: testcontainers

I have just started using testcontainers and I am getting into issues.  Below is my code:

```
 @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer redisContainer =
            new GenericContainer("corporateurl/redis:latest")
                   .withExposedPorts(6379);
```

When I run this without the exposedPorts it works fine but with exposedPorts it gives an error:

```
Could not start container
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container did not start correctly.
```

Any idea how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say since the exception doesn't provide any clues, I would suggest you try accessing logs:
https://www.testcontainers.org/features/container_logs/

Is 6379 available on localhost at the moment you start your test, any chance there is some other container?